# Unity - I cant see my mouse on screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a simple 3D game in Unity and for the most part everything works, but when my player dies the mouse is not visible on the death screen. [image: Canvas that the death screen is on]

[image: Here is the camera of the death screen]

I have two other scenes with what looks like to me the same exact settings, yet the mouse on those is visible.

Comment: Did you make the game completely by your self? If not, then check all of your scripts for `Cursor.visible` and `Cursor.lockState`. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check your script. search for Cursor.visible
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-visible.html